# selenium-webdriver: how to use driver.quit() in javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, driver, exit

How can I terminate ***driver*** instance without throwing an exception? Sometimes it quits before anything is done.

```js
driver.get('http://www.google.com');
var query = driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.name("q")));
query.sendKeys('webdriver\n');
driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search')); 
driver.quit();
```

Comment: you can try `driver.close();`

Comment: it is the same. :(

Comment: check this and search for titleContains, it might help https://huddle.eurostarsoftwaretesting.com/how-to-selenium-expected-conditions/

Answer (score 1):

Those methods return promises. So you need to wait for them to execute those operations in order.
For example

```
await driver.get('http://www.google.com');
```

See https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver#usage for more details

Answer (score 0):

you can also try the following function and call that function in your script

```
public void tearDown()
{
 if(driver!=null)
 {
  driver.quit();
 }
}`
```